# Extjs retrieve label beforerender

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to load the text of a label on the beforerender event. So I attached the beforender event... as below

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'VOID',
    listeners: {
        beforerender: {
        fn: me.onLabelBeforeRender,
        scope: me
    }
},

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/who',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){
        var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        alert(text);
        // process server response here
    }
});
```

And now I would like to change the label from VOID into the response value of /who However I fail to see how I can access that label in a decent way. Of course I can add an id use getcmp however that seems so clumsy, or is that the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as far as performance goes, an id + `Ext.getCmp()` is the most efficient option. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872261/extjs4-1-up-down-versus-ext-getcmp/11873049#11873049) for more.

It will definitely be faster than adding a listener, for which you get quite a healthy call stack.

Comment: Never use static ID and getCmp.This is the worst way that can be in ExtJS

Answer (score 0):

define the label like this

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'VOID',
    itemId:'someLabel',
    listeners: {
        beforerender: {
        fn: me.onLabelBeforeRender,
        scope: me
    }
}
```

now because you are keeping the scope as `me` which im assuming is some ancestor of label so with in the `onLabelBeforeRender` function you can access `me` by the `this` keyword. so in that function retrieve the label as

```
var label = this.down('label[itemId="someLabel"]');
label.setText('WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE');
```

Comment: Is equal to `this.down('#someLabel')`