# Extjs Menu Check Items - How to call?

Tags: checkbox, extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1 as part of my project. So every Extjs component in view.js , I could call it using Ext.getCmp and use it anywhere in my code.

My problem is with Menu Check Items.. I couldn't find a way to call each item and check for selection in anywhere but view.js !! I need those items to be checked in another part of my project but I have no idea how to do that !

My handler:

```
myHandler: function (menucheckitem, checked, opts) {
    switch (menucheckitem.getId ()) {
        // Here handles the first
        case 'first':
            if (checked) {
                console.log ('First checked!');
                goToFunction ();
            }
            break;
        // Here handles the second
        case 'second':
            if (checked) {
                console.log ('Second checked!');
                goToFunction ();
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log ('Whatever!');
    }
}
```

As you see above, if I want to send each menucheckitem to another js file and check for selection.. How I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ext.getCmp is not considered a best practice. You can use ComponentQuery class to target your desired component. See other SO questions about getCmp.

[up() and down() versus Ext.getCmp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872261/extjs4-1-up-down-versus-ext-getcmp/11874707#11874707)