# Testing extjs apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

How can I test extjs application when there are pregerated ids for components or compoent parts like in a grid.

I can add ids to each component but what if I miss one or more, and the application is big and complex?

Is there a function or some module in ExtJS/Siesta which allows you to locate components/elements in the application without beign dependent on predefined ids for each component

Comment: you can explicitly set ID's for an element and use Ext.get or Ext.getCmp

Comment: the general consensus seems to be: be caredul with cmp.id, use itemId and 'this.down('#' + theItemId);' (or 'this.up()') instead. Here we're talking ExtJS.ComponentQuery which gives you other things to play with such as class names, xtypes and css classes a la jQuery selectors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all be [very careful using IDs on the components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874707/834424). I have seen my fair share of problems with them.

Second, ExtJS provides several ways of targeting Components and Elements. Don't mix the two.

For Components:

- Ext.getCmp(id)
- [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).query()
- [up()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-up)
- [down()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-down)
- [nextSibling()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-nextSibling)
- [previousSibling()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-previousSibling)
- [child()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-child)
- [previousNode()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-previousNode)

plus various `find..` methods

For Elements:

- [Ext.get()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-get)
- [Ext.dom.Query()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query)

more on DOM Query http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/domquery.html

Answer (score 1):

With Siesta you have loads of options when targeting a place to click etc:

- Dom node id (same as Ext Component id)
- Any component query
- Any CSS query
- A coordinate
- Real Ext Component JS instance
- Real DOM node instance
- Composite Query (combination of Component Query and CSS query, '.x-grid => .x-grid-cell'
- A function, returning any of the above.

More info in my slides here: https://speakerdeck.com/mats/testing-sencha-touch

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the automated functional GUI testing tool [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/extjs.html).

RIATest knows how to ignore ids dynamically generated by ExtJS, yet if you manually assign ids to the components the tool *will* use them for identification (see e.g. #tree2 in the sample below).

The tests in RIATest operate in terms of ExtJS UI widgets.

**Examples of RIATest scripts that work with ExtJS widgets:**

The following clicks on an ExtJS button with label "Next Page":

```
ExtButton("Next Page")=>click();
```

And the following does drag-n-drop of a row from one ExtJS tree to another:

```
ExtRow("Controller.js")=>dragAndDropTo(
    ExtTreePanel("#tree2")->ExtRow("Custom Ext JS"));
```

And this collapses the header of an ExtJS box:

```
ExtBox("Feeds")->ExtHeader("FeedsВ")->ExtCollapser()=>click();
```

*(All sample code above is from real test scripts that run on ExtJS sample applications).*

(Disclaimer: I am a RIATest team member).