# Navigating through DOM with Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having some trouble selecting the element I want on my page. The structure looks like:

```
<div id="Notepanel-1003_header" class="x-panel-header" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 737px;">
<div id="Notepanel-1003-body" class="x-panel-body" style="padding: 10px; width: 737px; height: 423px; left: 0px; top: 44px;" role="presentation" data-ref="body">
```

I can get it to select the `Notepanel-1003_header` with

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('Notepanel')[0].down()`  which gives me `<div id="Notepanel-1003_header" class="x-panel-header" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 737px;">`

But how do i go from here and select `Notepanel-1003-body` ? These two are on the same level, i tried to add .next() at the end, but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using class name as a selector?

Comment: Like Ext.ComponentQuery.query('x-panel-header') ?

Comment: why won't you add "itemId" property to the object?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an element, not a component.
Once you've got the component (using `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` as mentioned) you can use `getEl()` to get the component's element and then use `down()` with a standard CSS selector (id, class name etc.).

Answer (score 0):

First is worth to separate the concept of Components ([Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Component), [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)) and (DOM) Elements ([Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element), [Ext.dom.Query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query)).

To navigate through DOM with Extjs you can use

1. Ext.query (what is alias for [Ext.dom.Query.select()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query), its support element selectors, attribute selectors, pseudo classes and even CSS value selectors, XML namespaces. You can do something like this:

   ```
   Ext.dom.Query.select('div#Notepanel-1003-body')
   ```

   It will return HTML DOM element
2. Ext.get (what is alias for [Ext.dom.Element.get()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-static-method-get)) using the id of the node, a DOM Node or an existing Element as its argument. You can do something like this:

   ```
   Ext.get('Notepanel-1003-body')
   ```

   It will return [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)

   Worth noting is that the [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) contains many methods to navigate thought DOM, for example:

   - [up()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-up)
   - [down()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-down)
   - [next()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-next)

     ```
     Ext.get('Notepanel-1003_header').next('div')
     ```

Also you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363598/extjs-4-best-way-to-select-an-element).