# Accessing an iframe inside a tab panel extjs4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a tab panel formed of two tabs. I'm trying to access the iframe in each tab by using "window.frames["id"]" but i'm getting undefined when alerting it. How to access the iframe in my case?

```
 tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            region: 'center',
            activeTab: 0,
            autoScroll: true,
            items: [
                    {   
                        id:"panel_A",
                        title: "${tr.A}",
                        html: "<iframe src= '"+A_url +"' width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_A' name='frm_A' frameborder=0 />",
                    },{
                        id:"panel_B",
                        title: "${tr.B}",
                        //disabled:tabs_status,
                        //hidden:hidden,
                        html: "<iframe src='"+B_url +"'  width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_B' name='frm_B' frameborder=0 />",
                    }]
            });


        viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
            layout:'border',
            items:[tabPanel]
        });
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason as to why you are electing to use IFRAMEs instead of using standard ExtJS panels for your tabs?

Comment: Oh, and to access your IFRAMEs from the DOM you should just use `document.getElementById('frm_A')`

Answer (score 0):

To select DOM elements you can use [Ext.dom.Query.select()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query-method-select), alias `Ext.query()`.

> Ext.dom.Query Provides high performance selector/xpath processing by compiling queries into reusable functions. New pseudo classes and matchers can be plugged. It works on HTML and XML documents (if a content node is passed in).

More about navigating through DOM with ExtJS in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363789/2667065).

Try something like `Ext.query('iframe#frm_A');`

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13v2)

Comment: I'm getting blank alert

Comment: Try to `console.log()` it?

Comment: I didn't get anything

Comment: Added fiddle to answer, its appear in a console. Maybe you try to query iframe while your `tabpanel` not created yet?

Comment: if that's the case what do you suggest me doing?

Comment: Depends of your code, just make sure that you create and render your tabpanel before `Ext.query('iframe#frm_A');`.