# Saving several tab panels with one button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have three seperate tab panels with each being a table in my database. What i'm trying to do is that on a click of a button is save the content of all the three tabs in the database at the same time. I managed to get the PK "Aid" of the current active tab, however when i try to access the second inactive tab B with window.frames["frm_B"] and alerting the result, i'm getting undefined. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        region: 'center',
        activeTab: 0,
        autoScroll: true,
        tbar: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Save',
            handler:function(){saveForm("frm_A", save);}
        }],
        items: [
                {   
                    id:"panel_A",
                    html: "<iframe src= '"+A_url +"' width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_A' name='frm_A' frameborder=0 />",
                },{
                    id:"panel_B",
                    html: "<iframe src='"+B_url+"'  width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_B' name='frm_B' frameborder=0 />",
                },{
                    id:"panel_C",
                    html: "<iframe src= '"+C_url+"' width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_C' name='frm_C' frameborder=0 />",
                }]
        });


    viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'border',
        items:[tabPanel]
    });

    function save(record){

        var Aid = record.getKey();
        var doc =  window.frames["frm_B"];
        alert(doc);
        try {
            doc.RECORD.getField("A_ID").setRealValue(Aid);
            doc.RECORD.update(closeAndRefresh, viewExtError);

        }
        catch(e){
            showError(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an iframe inside a tab panel extjs4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831078/accessing-an-iframe-inside-a-tab-panel-extjs4-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is that your `<iframe name='frm_B'>` is not rendered (added to DOM) when you try to get it with `window.frames["frm_B"]`.

When you create tab panel with `Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {});` you just create JS object, not all of its `items: []` added to DOM immediatelly.

> A Container's child Components are rendered by that Container's layout
>   manager when the Container is first rendered.

For example tabpanel tabs added to DOM when you first time open that tab.

[Fiddle to illustrate it](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13v2)

*Solution for your question depends on your code actually, but as workaround you can use `.render()` method of tab panel child panels...*

Comment: Thank you for illustrating the problem. Do you mind telling where exactly to use .render() ? please

Comment: Well, as I said it depends of your code. You use `iframe` instead of common ExtJS components so I guess your logic is not common. I added two buttons to illustrate usage of `.render()` method and how you can manually render it via layout manager, but its far from final solution.

Comment: `deferredRender` config on the tab panel.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov dear any chance to apply your solution on the creation of the tab pannel?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli i added  config : {        
                  deferredRender : true  
                   },

Comment: `deferredRender: false` and its property of `Ext.tab.Panel`, not its child items - check docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-deferredRender