# Ext js get value of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a component which has an input type specified under the HTML propertie so that it renders like an input type. But I have trouble geetting the value of the input type....

Component:

```
xtype: 'component',
html: {
    html: '<input id=\'colorPickerBackground\' type=\'color\' onchange=\'myFunction()\' ></input>'
},
itemId: 'colorPicker',
listeners: {
    afterrender: {
        fn: me.onComponentAfterRender,
        scope: me
    }
}
```

On a certain Ext.js event I want to get the value of the input type inside html??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case code you can do something like this:

```
afterrender: function(component) {
    // Color input is Ext.dom.Element instance
    var colorInput = component.getEl().down('#colorPickerBackground');
    // Use .down('#colorPickerBackground', true) to get actual DOM element
}
```

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15q5)

More about navigating through DOM with ExtJS in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363789/2667065).

*Since you trying to create color picker you have to look at [`Ext.picker.Color`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Color).*

*If you still want to do it on your own take a look at [`Ext.form.field.Base`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base), you can use it as base for your color picker.*

Comment: ext.picker.Color has only 40 colors I need more

Comment: Better written as `component.getEl().down('#foo');`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I agree, just wanted to point out the use of `Ext.dom.Query.select`.

Comment: @JacobSo So I thought, in that case, I described how you can get the value of the field.

Comment: I keep getting: d.getElementById is not a function
triggered by     console.log(Ext.query('#colorPickerBackground', component.getEl())[0].value);

Comment: @Jacob Can you update provided fiddle to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli With this code I actually get `Ext.dom.Element`, not actual DOM element, so I have to use ExtJS's `.on()` instead of JS's `addEventListener()`

Comment: @Jacob Updated my fiddle, check it out