# Access the values of different tabs in extjs4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have created a tab panel in extjs4.2 , and what i'm trying to do is access the values in the form of a tab while being in the other tab. For example the user is on tab A and have access to the values in tab B. How can access the other tab?

```
tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        region: 'center',
        activeTab: 0,
        autoScroll: true,
        items: [
                {   
                    id:"panel_A",
                    title: "${tr.A}",
                    html: "<iframe src= '"+A_url +"' width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_A' name='frm_A' frameborder=0 />",
                },{
                    id:"panel_B",
                    title: "${tr.B}",
                    //disabled:tabs_status,
                    //hidden:hidden,
                    html: "<iframe src='"+B_url +"'  width='100%' height='100%' id='frm_B' name='frm_B' frameborder=0 />",
                }]
        });


    viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'border',
        items:[tabPanel]
    });
```

In this part on a click of a button i'm able to access the current frame.

```
new Ext.Toolbar.Button({
                        id:"btn_show",
                        text: "${tr.Show}",
                        tooltip: "${tr.Show}",
                        handler: function(){view(frmid);}
                    }),

     function view(frmid) {

             var A_key =   window.frames[frmid].RECORD.getKey();
            /* var B_key = window.frames[...].RECORD.getField("HISTORY").getRealValue();*/



        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select [Ext.ComponentView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Component) you can use [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).

> Provides searching of Components within Ext.ComponentManager (globally) or a specific Ext.container.Container on the document with a similar syntax to a CSS selector. Returns Array of matching Components, or empty Array.

More about selectors for DOM Elements and ExtJS Components in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364970/2667065).

Basic example of how you can access another tab of a `tabpanel`:

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13v3)

```
// If you button is child / parent button of a tabpanel its efficient to use down() / up() methods
// Since we get button component reference as listener function arguments we can select parent tabpanel component,
// and after it select child component panel (because panel is default xtype for tabpanel items and textfield after it
panelBTextFieldValue = button.up('tabpanel').down('panel[id=panel_B] textfield[name=panel_B_text_field]').getValue();

// If your button is somewhere else you can use Ext.ComponentQuery.query()
panelBTextFieldValue = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel[id=myPanel] panel[id=panel_B] textfield[name=panel_B_text_field]').getValue();

// or just if selector textfield[name=panel_B_text_field] specific enought for whole your application
panelBTextFieldValue = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=panel_B_text_field]').getValue();
```

Comment: If its not exactly what you want let me know and I'll update fiddle.

Comment: dear this is exactly what i want.. But can you please explain to me the concept behind this line of code: panelBTextFieldValue = button.up('tabpanel').down('panel[id=panel_B] textfield[name=panel_B_text_field]').getValue()

I mean why i'm specifying it's a textfield

Comment: Updated fiddle and answer, if somesing else is unclear feel free to ask, I'll try to help.

Comment: In ExtJS component selectors is quite similat to CSS selectors, instead of HTML tag name you have to use component alias(xtype), thus we select textfied with `textfield[name=panel_B_text_field]` or we can jsut use `textfield` or `[name=panel_B_text_field]` if its specific enought.